# OpenGL drawing rectangle with mouse drag?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, glut

I'm trying to draw a shape like you do with the tool in paint, where you drag it and when you release the mouse and it will draw the shape.

Currently what my program does is that if you click it will come up with the rubber band to show you what the shape looks like, but nothing gets drawn when you release the mouse click.

The relevant code is as follows:

```
// this function draws the list of objects
void drawList() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear display window.
    if (list[numObj].t==1){
        glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
        glVertex2i(list[numObj].x1, list[numObj].y1);
        glVertex2i(list[numObj].x1, list[numObj].y2);
        glVertex2i(list[numObj].x2, list[numObj].y2);
        glVertex2i(list[numObj].x2, list[numObj].y1);
        glEnd();
    }
    glFlush();
}

void mouseDraw(GLint button, GLint action, GLint xMouse, GLint yMouse) {
    if (type == 1){
        if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON) {
            if (action == GLUT_DOWN && button != GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON && numObj < MaxNumObj -1) {
                list[numObj].x1 = xMouse;
                list[numObj].y1 = yMouse;
                list[numObj].x2 = xMouse;
                list[numObj].y2 = yMouse;
                list[numObj].t = type;
                list[numObj].s = 2;
                list[numObj].r = red;
                list[numObj].g = green;
                list[numObj].b = blue;
                glutPostRedisplay();

            } else if (action == GLUT_UP && button != GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON) {
                list[numObj].x2 = xMouse;
                list[numObj].y2 = yMouse;
                list[numObj].s = style;
                numObj++;
                glutPostRedisplay();
            }
        }
    }
}

// this function takes the mouse position while moving mouse, use this for intermediate drawing
void Motion(GLint x, GLint y) {
    // add the (x, y) coordinates of the second point to the intermediate rectangle
    list[numObj].x2 = x;
    list[numObj].y2 = y;
    // redisplay the object list after the above insertion. It will give a rubber band effect

    glutPostRedisplay ( );
}
```

relevant main code:

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
glutInitWindowSize(winWidth, winHeight);
glutCreateWindow("SimpleDraw Example");

init();

// register call back funtions
glutDisplayFunc(drawList);
glutReshapeFunc(winReshapeFcn);
glutMouseFunc(mouseDraw);
glutMotionFunc(Motion);

//add right click menu
glutAttachMenu(GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON);

glutMainLoop();
```

Please ignore the .s .t and stuff, the only relevant things should be the x and ys.

Here are some gifs to show my current outcome and the desired outcome:

my current program
[image: my current program]

what I want it to do
[image: what I want it to do]

Comment: it looks like it should work ... what compiler? My bet is `(action == GLUT_UP && button != GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON)`  is not evaluated as you think try `((action == GLUT_UP) && (button != GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON))` and in the other if too... is `list[]` allocated (staticaly or dynamicaly) with bigger size than 1? How are you deciding you render an edited object? either add some bool or increment the `numobj` on mouse down and use `numobj-1` as index later on. Do you render objects in loop?

Comment: It's working now! as Rabbid76 suggested I just had to draw my list of objects, so I just used a for loop to go from 0 to numObj and draw the existing objects in the beginning of the draw function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to draw all the rectangles, that you have stored in your `list`, from the first till the last:

```
void drawList() {

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear display window.

    for( size_t i = 0; i <= numObj; ++ i ) {

        if (list[numObj].t==1){

            glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
            glVertex2i(list[i].x1, list[i].y1);
            glVertex2i(list[i].x1, list[i].y2);
            glVertex2i(list[i].x2, list[i].y2);
            glVertex2i(list[i].x2, list[i].y1);
            glEnd();
        }
    }
    glFlush();
}
```